# using a for loop to determine the distance between two points from a uniform distribution

Tags: r

If Xm~uniform(-25,25),Ym~uniform(-25,25) and  r~uniform(0,25), θ~uniform(0,2π)  and Xf=rcosθ, Yf=rsinθ.

I want to use a for loop to create 5000 independent variables of point (Xm,Ym) and (Xf,Yf) then calculate the distance between the two points. i know how to calculate the distance between points but creating 5000 realisations of (Xm,Ym) and (Xf,Yf) I am finding tricky. here is my attempt:

Now for Xf,Yf I took a similar approach  to Xm,Ym

```
for (i in 1:5000)
{
res=c()
repeat{
Xm=runif(1,min=-25,max=25)
Ym=runif(1,min=-25,max=25)
if(Xm**2+Ym**2<=25**2)
res=rbind(res,data.frame(Xm,Ym))
break
{
  res=rbind(res,data.frame(Xm,Ym))
}



    for (i in 1:5000)
    {
    res=c()
    repeat{
   R=runif(1,min=0,max=25)
0=runif(1,min=0,max=2*pi)
    Xf=Rcos(0)
    Yf=Rsin(0)
    Yf=runif(1,min=-25,max=25)
    if(Xf**2+Yf**2<=25**2)
    res=rbind(res,data.frame(Xf,Yf))
    break
    {
      res=rbind(res,data.frame(Xf,Yf))
    }

     D=sqrt((Xm-Xf)**2+(Ym-Yf)**2))
```

Comment: Do you really need it to be a loop?
You can use `sample()` to get 5000 points of Xm or in the same `runif(n=5000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach without loop:

```
# Yours data
set.seed(9) # Just for reprodutibility

npoints = 5000

# Vectors with 5000 points
Xm=runif(n = npoints,min=-25,max=25)
Ym=runif(n = npoints,min=-25,max=25)

theta = runif(n = npoints, min = 0, max = 2*pi)
R = runif(n = npoints,min = 0, max = 25) 
Xf = R*cos(theta)
Yf = R*sin(theta)

D = sqrt((Xm-Xf)^2+(Ym-Yf)^2)
```